Gemini AI is not available in my Android Studio
It's well known that Gemini is now supported in Android Studio. But as we know that Gemini has a limitation for some country. Well, I can run Gemini with all of my Google Accounts at the Gemini Webstie:

But for some reason that I don't know, I can't run Gemini in my Android Studio with the same Google Account. It appears like this:

My Android Studio is the latest version (Koala) and I'm running on my Mac. Is there any configuration that I need to change or something?
Edit: I live in Indonesia, and Google stated that Gemini is available in Indonesia in this site. My friends got Gemini in their Android Studio. But why don't I?

As the message states. Gemini in Android Studio currently not available in your country.
Remember Gemini the web application is not the same as Gemini in Android Studio.   This is a different system.
You should check the Gemini in Android Studio availability page to ensure that your country is supported.

I live in Indonesia, and my friends can use gemini in their Android Studio. But why don't I?

Indonesia seems to be available i would check and make sure that your internet connection shows you being in Indonesia

I have no problem with my internet connection. My friends can use Gemini with the same connection as I am.

Did you manage to find the problem? I have the same issue, my country is supported but the Gemini tool is not working inside Android Studio, it says "Apologies, Gemini in Android Studio is currently not available in your country."

@RakaM.A this question is for you :)
